# Not ever downloaded from Webservice item is displayed in the ListView

Tags: android, web-services, api, android-volley

I've got problem with webservice.I download JSONObject , parse it , and display in recyclerView. I'm using Volley library. My code looks like this :

```
@Override
    protected List<Concert> doInBackground(String... params) {
        final List<Concert> concerts = new ArrayList<>();
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://krakowskascenamuzyczna.pl/api/koncerty/future/",
                new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject responseJSONObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String arrayString = responseJSONObject.getJSONArray("posts").toString();
                        JSONArray responseJSONArray = new JSONArray(arrayString);
                        Concert tempConcert;
                        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + responseJSONArray.length());
                        for (int i = 0; i < responseJSONArray.length(); i++) {
                            tempConcert = new Concert(responseJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("attachments").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("images").getJSONObject("full").getString("url"),
                                    responseJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("content"),
                                    responseJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("date"),
                                    responseJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"),
                                    responseJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"),
                                    responseJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("type"),
                                    responseJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("custom_fields").getJSONArray("typ").getInt(0));

                            concerts.add(tempConcert);
                            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: size" + concerts.size() );
                        }
```

Length of responseJSONArray is 10 while concerts is 3 and I've got exactly 3 concerts in my recyclerView. Why not every downloaded concert is added to list ?

Comment: Does the log "onResponse: size" inside for loop prints 10 times ??

Comment: If your sure that you get ten responses, you should be looking at the implementation of your RecyclerView.

Comment: onResponse: size" prints 3 times. I found that I get org.json.JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0)

Comment: I assume that getJSONArray("attachments") is empty in the 4th item. So getJSONObject(0) will trigger exception & for loop is breaked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray postsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts");
    JSONObject postObject;
    Concert tempConcert;
    JSONArray attachmentArray;
    JSONObject imageObject;
    JSONObject fullObject;
    JSONArray typArray;
    JSONObject customFieldObject;
    for (int i = 0; i < postsArray.length(); i++) {
        postObject = postsArray.getJSONObject(i);
        tempConcert = new Concert();
        tempConcert.setId(postObject.getInt("id"));
        tempConcert.setTitle(postObject.getString("title"));
        attachmentArray = postObject.getJSONArray("attachments");
        if (attachmentArray != null && attachmentArray.length() > 0) {
            imageObject = ((JSONObject) attachmentArray.get(0)).getJSONObject("images");
            if (imageObject != null) {
                fullObject = imageObject.getJSONObject("full");
                if (fullObject != null) {
                    tempConcert.setUrl(fullObject.getString("url"));
                }
            }
        }
        tempConcert.setContent(postObject.getString("content"));
        tempConcert.setDate(postObject.getString("date"));
        tempConcert.setType(postObject.getString("type"));
        customFieldObject = postObject.getJSONObject("custom_fields");
        if (customFieldObject != null) {
            typArray = customFieldObject.getJSONArray("typ");
            if (typArray != null && typArray.length() > 0) {
                tempConcert.setTyp((String) typArray.get(0));
            }
        }
        concerts.add(tempConcert);
    }
    Log.e("tag", "onResponse: size" + concerts.size());
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("TAG", "Exception caught : " + e1);

}
```

Comment: typ is Integer so linetempConcert.setTyp((String) typArray.get(0)); I changed to tempConcert.setTyp((int) typArray.get(0)); but I get java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: A little modification and works perfectly :) Thanks a lot!!! You saved my day! :)

Answer (score 1):

I did not get the point of doing

```
String arrayString = responseJSONObject.getJSONArray("posts").toString();

JSONArray responseJSONArray = new JSONArray(arrayString);
```

You can directly extract JSONArray from JSONObject.

Try this code

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray postsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts");
JSONObject postObject;
for (int i = 0; i < postsArray.length(); i++) {
     postObject = postsArray.getJSONObject(i);
     int id = postObject.getInt("id");
     String title = postObject.getString("title");
     Log.d("TAG", "#" + i);
     Log.d("TAG", "ID : " + id + ", title : " + title);
}
```

I got this in Android Studio Logcat

[image]

As you clearly see the count is 10.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I did it your way but still got only 3 items :/

Comment: Are you getting any exception ?

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0)